# sql order by 2 columns, one manual and one asc

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I am trying to insert into a table by selecting two columns from another table. I want to order it, first by the first column manually (bronze, silver then gold), then by the second column in ascending order. I found an answered question that allowed me to order the ranks by bronze/silver/gold, OR I can order the numbers column, but I cant get it to do both at once.

This is how I'm ordering it with bronze/silver/gold:

```
-- The Code:
drop table test5;
drop sequence id5_seq;

create table test5 
(id_num number primary key, 
ranks varchar(20), 
numbers number);

create sequence id5_seq
minvalue 1
maxvalue 10000
start with 1
increment by 1
nocycle;

create or replace trigger auto_test5_id
before insert on test5
for each row
begin
:NEW.id_num := id5_seq.nextval;
end;
/
insert into test5(ranks,numbers) (select distinct ranking,numbering from temp1 where ranking is not null) order by case
when ranking = 'Bronze' then 1 
when ranking = 'Silver' then 2
when ranking = 'Gold' then 3
else 4
end
;

select * from test5;


-- The Results:

Table TEST5 dropped.


Sequence ID5_SEQ dropped.


Table TEST5 created.


Sequence ID5_SEQ created.


Trigger AUTO_TEST5_ID compiled

14 rows inserted.


    ID_NUM RANKS                   NUMBERS
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Bronze                       32
         2 Bronze                       80
         3 Bronze                       16
         4 Bronze                      160
         5 Bronze                        8
         6 Bronze                      190
         7 Silver                        4
         8 Gold                        190
         9 Gold                         94
        10 Gold                         32
        11 Gold                          8
        12 Gold                         80
        13 Gold                         64
        14 Gold                         16

 14 rows selected
```

My goal is to get the end result to look like this:

```
    ID_NUM RANKS                   NUMBERS
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Bronze                        8
         2 Bronze                       16
         3 Bronze                       32
         4 Bronze                       80
         5 Bronze                      160
         6 Bronze                      190
         7 Silver                        4
         8 Gold                          8
         9 Gold                         16
        10 Gold                         32
        11 Gold                         64
        12 Gold                         80
        13 Gold                         94
        14 Gold                        190
```

I am using SQL developer Oracle 11g.
Thank you everyone for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add numbering field , not sure with the insert syntax of oracle

```
insert into test5(ranks,numbers)
select distinct ranking,numbering from temp1 where ranking is not null  order by (case
when ranking = 'Bronze' then 1 
when ranking = 'Silver' then 2
when ranking = 'Gold' then 3
else 4
end)
   , numbering -- to sort asc
```